# Can't get every folder of /path/

Tags: applescript

I write a code as

```
  set localaccount to {"1", "2"}
set locacc to choose from list localaccount with prompt "Select your Account Location:" default items {"1"}


set accounstlist to POSIX path of thisFolder & "accountlist.txt"
set folderloc to POSIX path of thisFolder & locacc
tell application "System Events"
    set applicationNames to name of folders of folderloc
end tell
set {TID, text item delimiters} to {text item delimiters, linefeed}
set namesText to applicationNames as text
set text item delimiters to TID
try
    set fileDescriptor to open for access accounstlist with write permission
    write namesText to fileDescriptor
    close access fileDescriptor
on error e number n
    try
        close access file accounstlist
    end try
    display dialog "Error: " & e & " - number: " & n buttons {"Cancel"} default button "Cancel"
end try
set theaccounts to paragraphs of (read accounstlist)
set theaccount to choose from list theaccounts with prompt "Select Account You Want To Export"
```

but on run it gives me Can't get every folder of /path/
path is "folderloc"
Can anyone help me?

Comment: As an example, what might the value of `thisFolder` be ?  And what would you expect the values of `folderloc` and `accounstlist` to be ?

Comment: Thanks, 'thisfolder' get a folder with choose folder command from user, accountlist should be something like this:
if user input desktop/somefolder , accountlist is: desktop/somefolder/accountlist.txt and folderloc is desktop/somefolder/locacc which locacc is whatever user select from the list.

Comment: i tested the result with display dialog command in each section, path values are correct, but I don't know why it gives me error on getting folder list

Comment: Thanks for the clarification.  It’s an easy fix, as well as quite a few other things that I will provide suggestions for you to review.  I will have a bit more time to do this later.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well done for solving it yourself.  The issue was almost certainly in the *System Events* block, where you were trying to retrieve a list of folders from `folderloc`.  In your original script, `folderloc` was simply a string containing a plain text posix path, so it made no sense when you asked *System Events* to get the folders from a piece of text.  Your edit solved this by converting the posix path into a `POSIX file` and then into an `alias`, which *System Events* could then access to get your list of folders.

Here's a corrected version of your script with a lot of the excess fat trimmed away that wasn't necessary:

```
set localaccount to {"1", "2"}
set locacc to choose from list localaccount with prompt "Select your Account Location:" default items {"1"}
set accounstlist to POSIX path of thisFolder & "accountlist.txt"
set folderloc to POSIX path of thisFolder & locacc
set text item delimiters to linefeed
tell application "System Events" to set namesText to ¬
        (name of folders of folder folderloc) as text
write namesText to accounstlist
set theaccounts to paragraphs of (read accounstlist)
set theaccount to choose from list theaccounts with prompt "Select Account You Want To Export"
```

Comment: Can you please see this post also, 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63435336/how-to-show-a-dialog-windows-during-applescript-works

Answer (score 1):

I managed to solve the problem by changing the code like this:

```
set accounstlist1 to POSIX path of thisFolder & "accountlist.txt"
    set accounstlist1 to POSIX file accounstlist1
    set accounstlist to accounstlist1 as alias
    set folderloc1 to POSIX path of thisFolder & locacc
    set folderloc1 to POSIX file folderloc1
    set folderloc to folderloc1 as alias
```

problem was about  path.
thanks for al the help here.