# how to show a dialog windows during applescript works

Tags: applescript

I wrote an applescript to convert a to b,
I want to show a dialog when script is working,
script first ask for a file and a folder from user, after this I want to show a dialog until my last dialog which say work is done.
I couldn’t find any help here or other sites regarding this way of implementing dialogs, thanks for you help.
to be clear, there is no way of having an input for steps, because it's doing a convert on one file only, but the file could be large & take some time, I'm looking for something that can input for example line of codes & progress depend on which line it's working right now or something else which start with the first line & close just before the end dialog

Comment: AppleScript provides a [progress window](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/MacAutomationScriptingGuide/DisplayProgress.html)

Comment: Thanks, I know this one, but as I mentioned, because I can't input any number fro the progress, I can't use it,

Comment: You could show the indeterminate progress view (the spinning one).

Comment: It's ok, I don't need any progress bar, just something that tells that script is running, but it should show as a dialog on screen, not in menubar

Comment: Take a look at Dialog ToolKit Plus on https://latenightsw.com/support/freeware/ , an AppleScriptObjC script library.

Comment: Thanks so much, I can't use any external script, as In the final the app to be used on a closed system that I don't have any access to other folders other than application folder.

Comment: You can put the script library also into the application bundle. Or you can show an (asynchronous) dialog window with AppleScriptObjC in the app.

Comment: Thanks for all the answers, unfortunately I didn’t have any chance with this.

Comment: Can you show your AppleScript that converts `a` to `b` ?

Comment: I'm not sure why the 'progress' wouldn't work for your case. The example at the link (in the first comment) should work almost as is. You can work with a single file and then at the end of the conversion, increase the 'progress completed steps' from 0 to 1. Alternatively, you can set an arbitrary number of steps and increment the progress after each line of code. It seems ideal for your purpose.